# Opção "Cancelar" GetOpenFilename(Multiselect:= True)

Tags: vba, excel-vba

eu tenho a seguinte dúvida, eu quero usar o código com a propriedade `Multiselect = True` que retorna uma Variant() como resultado, no entanto, quando eu clico em "cancelar" ele retorna  `False`, resultando no seguinte erro:

Erro em tempo de execução 13 "tipos incompatíveis".

Código abaixo:

```
public sub open_file()
dim i as integer
Dim filename() As Variant

filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Arquivos em Excel", MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Arquivos em Excel,*.xls*")

For i = 1 To UBound(filename)

    msgbox filename(i)

next i

end sub
```

Alguma ideia de como solucionar esse erro?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema

Com `Multiselect:=True`, filename será um vetor ou uma booleana, por isso os tipos são incopatíveis e uma condicional precisa ser criada para verificar qual tipo de dado é retornado.

Caso o botão "Cancelar" seja clicado, `filename` é a booleana False:

[image: Booleana False]

Caso um arquivo ou mais sejam selecionados, `filename` é um vetor com Strings de caminhos para os arquivos selecionados.

[image: Vetor]

#### Código

```
Public Sub open_file()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim filename As Variant
    
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Arquivos em Excel", MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Arquivos em Excel,*.xls*")

    If IsArray(filename) Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(filename)
            MsgBox filename(i)
        Next i
    ElseIf filename = False Then
        MsgBox "Nenhum arquivo foi selecionado."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```